# ZwQueryInformationFile() on Windows 64 bits

Tags: c++, windows, driver, kernel-mode

I have the following code that works fine on Windows 32, already when tested on Windows 64 the text (the path of file) comes missing somes bytes, example:

- *\Program Files\Folder Software\Subfolder\123456.dll* > Windows 32 OK
- *rogram Files\Folder Software\Subfolder\123456.dll* > Windows 64 comes missing some first bytes

this is a bug of [`ZwQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwqueryinformationfile) on Win64 or there is something wrong with the following code that i'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <windef.h>

NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ZwQueryInformationFile(IN HANDLE FileHandle, OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, OUT PVOID FileInformation, IN ULONG Length, IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass);

HANDLE GetFileHandle(IN PCWSTR FileName, IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, IN ULONG ShareAccess)
{
    NTSTATUS ntStatus;
    UNICODE_STRING uniFileName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    HANDLE ntFileHandle;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatus;

    if (KeGetCurrentIrql() > PASSIVE_LEVEL) 
    {
        DbgPrint("KeGetCurrentIrql() > PASSIVE_LEVEL \n");
        return 0;
    }

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniFileName, FileName);

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objectAttributes, &uniFileName, OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE | OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);

    ntStatus = IoCreateFile(&ntFileHandle, DesiredAccess, &objectAttributes, &ioStatus, 0, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, ShareAccess, FILE_OPEN, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, IO_NO_PARAMETER_CHECKING);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus)) 
    {
        DbgPrint("IoCreateFile() error - 0x%X \n", ntStatus);
        return 0;
    }

    return ntFileHandle;
}

void test()
{
    POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION pfni;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatus = { 0 };
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE hFileHandle;
    SIZE_T allocSize;
    
    hFileHandle = GetFileHandle(L"\\??\\C:\\Program Files\\Folder Software\\Subfolder\\123456.dll", FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_DELETE);

    if (hFileHandle != NULL) 
    {
        allocSize = sizeof(OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION) + MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR);

        pfni = (POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)(ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, allocSize));

        if (pfni != NULL) 
        {
            RtlZeroMemory(pfni, allocSize);

            status = ZwQueryInformationFile(hFileHandle, &IoStatus, pfni, allocSize, FileNameInformation);

            if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
                DbgPrint("ZwQueryInformationFile() error - 0x%X \n", status);
            else
                DbgPrint("Filename: %ws \n", &pfni->Name.Buffer);

            ExFreePool(pfni);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ZwQueryInformationFile` with `FileNameInformation` return `FILE_NAME_INFORMATION` but not `OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION`

Comment: @RbMm, thank you. Solved.